# UX Process / Requirements

Tags: requirements, process

Yes it is kind of long.  So please just skip if me getting to the point is going to frustrate you.

I am in an arrangement with a re-seller where they have exclusive rights to my software in a market segment but I still own the software.  It is document management and the segment is litigation support.  I had zero penetration in litigation and was not going to get there without partner.

Prior to partnering with me the litigation partner tried hiring a developer and got no where.  There was not a single piece of documentation or even any running code.

After a few years we have a marginally successful product. Technically it smokes - it is fast and scales.

The UX is where we have problems.  Technical users like it. I have had to try and learn how an attorney thinks by trial and error.  Don't say have design sessions as that is not my role.  I will always be a handshake away from my end customers.

The problem is lack of documentation from the partner on requirements.  I will get one line or even verbal requirements.  Then I write the code and I get "but an attorney does not think that way or that is not how they want to use it".  The process is basically the partner puts all of 10 minutes into a requirement and I spend days or weeks developing it and they have me keep making revisions until they decide I got it right.  Then if a bug comes up in the revision process they neener-neener me like I have encumbered the process.

After we finally cycle to a solution they approve then my documentation is wrong as that is not what an attorney will understand.  My response every time is then why did you not tell me that up front what language to use.  I want/need a feature definition the customer will understand.

From day one I have told them that as a developer I need written functional requirements.  I need use cases.  If you tell me how an attorney talks I will put that in the documentation.  If you know how an attorney thinks then document it.

With all of this the segment is financially successful and has growth potential.  But it is so frustrating to me that I am ready to drop it.

So in summary the question is.  If marketing asserts they know the answer to UX then how do you tell them then put it in writing?   UX is way more than placing a button.

Comment: I agree, your situation is pretty bad, and I hope that you find a way out of it. But I don't see how a question here helps you, and worse, I don't think this question fits the rules. If you are asking if what he's doing is correct, then no, but you already know it. If you are asking how to communicate to your business partner so he doesn't feel slighted, then this is not a UX problem. If you are asking how to teach an unqualified person to be a requirements engineer, then it is too broad. I wish you the best, but I will still vote to close. Other communities may be better suited for advice.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about communication with one's business partner.

Comment: @RumiP. But it would be the same question if this an internal marketing department.  But it still might not be a good fit here.

Comment: I agree the question is not a good fit and have flagged it as please delete.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this should be written in your agreement, where you agree to provide the system design services and they agree to get you info that you require. When it comes to UX or UCD (user-centered design), requirements, including TA description, PRD and use cases are the most crucial info you can get from your employer/client. 
That would be the first thing to say.

Second, all requirements should come in text form, in Jira or in CML, Confluence, Trello, email — you name it. Never over Skype or phone call. If you do get them via phone call, don't start work until you get a follow-up of the discussion in text, signed (approved) by someone in charge.

Third, get the product manager or product owner give you written (in email) approval of these requirements. It's their job to define what the product should look and work like. 
So if later on someone renders them off, the responsibility is on PM/PO. After couple sessions of being bashed, chances are PO will start giving the approvals while conscious.

Fourth, there should not be several people involved in the decision making process. Your partner company should assign someone who is in charge, and that person's word should be the last for you.

If the combo of all above doesn't work, — if they resist, or the system and processes resist, consider quitting. It is extremely easy to get yourself burned out in the situation of constant frustration.

Comment: It is the owner that is the one giving me verbal requirements.

Comment: Well, sometimes owners don't realise this is a bad practice that burns company's time and money. And sometimes they don't want to be responsible. In any case, the owner needs to have some documented feedback from you on this. If it doesn't work, try pushing the feedback forward to the person above the product owner.

Comment: I don't  mean to deprive you of my up vote but I am going to go ahead and delete the question. I agree that it is not a good fit here.

Comment: No problem, Blam. I hope you situation works out. Btw I don't think this is an irrelevant question — process questions are important, too.

Comment: I think I should have worded it differently and take out that it is a partner. There is so much that has to go on before you get to a wire frame.  Is managing scope a UX issue?  I think it needs to be but kind of need to go with what the site decides is UX.

Comment: I agree, and I think gathering requirements is a crucial part of UX work, so I definitely consider it an UX issue. We learn (and share subsequently) all kinds of tools and practices but we get to discuss essential processes and boundaries so rarely. It takes me couple day to learn a new tool/software, or solve a problem, but it took me several years to figure out my professional boundaries. I think it is really important to speak about the processes.

Comment: If you would like to discuss this further then lets move to a chat.  I feel a big problem with the design process is the leverage a poor performer has to spoil the process.  A user that cannot grasp abstraction of requirement versus design goes straight to design and they are the person that should not be in design.  Articulating what (not how) a system needs to do and how those pieces fit together is hard work and in my mind wire frames hurt that process.  UX is cool but scope kills more projects than UX.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds extremely frustrating and a very old-school way of developing.

Bringing in agile methodologies might just save you and your sanity.

Start by working with the client about what features they want developed. This needs to include all dependencies and acceptance criteria - documented! All stakeholders (Marketing etc. ) need to sign-off these stories before you move into development.

If change comes up during development, create another "story" and place this in the backlog. Ask the client to prioritise this story, and explain to them that if they want this done the deadline needs to be extended.

In short you need to demand their time and get them to literally sign-off a story before it moves into development.

Comment: OK I agree.  Have tried design sessions and the problem I have there is I get "we need a button here that creates a report that looks like this."  We need use cases - what are the business rules to create that report.  If I let them talk and act as secretary they just sign off.  Then when it is done and they say but it doesn't do X and I say but it does what the spec says they say but your spec is too technical we didn't understand.